# How to debug a MacVim crash

Tags: macos, vim, osx-snow-leopard, macvim

I've been using MacVim (7.3 Build 53) on OSX Snow Leopard and every so often, the window will simply disappear, losing any unsaved changes I may have.  It is always the active window (if I have multiple windows open, they are unaffected) and it doesn't completely quit MacVim since it remains open on the Taskbar, just with no open windows.  There are no warnings or errors of any kind.

Normally to debug a mysterious vim related issue I would start by taking everything out of my config files and build them back up bit by bit checking if the error is still there however this problem is quite intermittent and (so far) I can't force it to reproduce the problem, so I'm not going to be able to tell for sure if the problem is fixed.

I've had a look for error logs and the such like but haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone have any suggestions for debugging this kind of issue?

Comment: You could report a bug to the [maintainer](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php#Support). There's also a mailing list for discussion.

Comment: Why don't you go through the proper channels? On [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/list) or [the vim-mac mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-mac), for example.

Comment: I would permanently log all activity and commands into a file by setting `verbosefile` and `verbose` to a high number.